# EF Core SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' despite configuring one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I looked through the documentation and several other answers but could not find what my problem was. I have a one to many relationship with `Student` and `ReportCard` like so

```
public class Student
{
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Grade CurrentGradeLevel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReportCard> ReportCards { get; set; }
}

public class ReportCard
{
    public long ReportCardId { get; set; }
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public double OverallGrade { get; set;}

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Grade GradeLevel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CourseGrade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

I configured the relationship in the `StudentContext` like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany(s => s.ReportCards)
                .WithOne(r => r.Student)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Yet when I try and delete a `ReportCard`, this error happens

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DELETE FROM "ReportCards"
      WHERE "ReportCardId" = @p0;
      SELECT changes();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Onero.Server.Models.ReportCardContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Onero.Server.Controllers.ReportCardController.DeleteReportCard(Int64 id) in /home/adrian/workspace/Onero/Server/Controllers/ReportCardController.cs:line 106
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter[7]
      An exception occurred while calculating the database error page content. Skipping display of the database error page.
      System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.Views.DatabaseErrorPage.ExecuteAsync()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.RazorViews.BaseView.ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter.HandleExceptionAsync(ErrorContext errorContext, Fun
```

Why might that be? I appreciate any help.

EDIT

Upon request, here is `CourseGrade`

```cs
    public class CourseGrade
    {
        public long CourseGradeId { get; set; }
        public long CourseModelId { get; set; }
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public double Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my delete api, which I had just called with postman

```cs
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteReportCard(long id)
        {
            var reportCard = await _context.ReportCards.FindAsync(id);
            if (reportCard == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.ReportCards.Remove(reportCard);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }
```

SECOND EDIT: included entire error message.

Comment: Can you post CourseGrade class too pls?

Comment: "I have both StudentContext and ReportCardContext" what is the difference and what context you posted here?

Comment: I posted StudentContext. ReportCardContext just has the DbSet of ReportCard.

Comment: CourseGrade is merely ``` long Id { get; set;} double Result { get; set; }```

Comment: How it is related to  IEnumerable<CourseGrade> Grades  ? Pls post a real code. It doesn' t make any sense  what you posted.

Comment: @Serge yes, sorry, I have posted the class.

Comment: @GertArnold I posted the method

Comment: So you just delete a `ReportCard`. In your code nothing refers *to* `ReportCard` so we can't tell you why a foreign key would be violated. Doesn't the Sqlite exception give any details on that?

Comment: And pls post Grade  class too. I  still can not see how  ICollection<CourseGrade> Grades can be connected to ReportCard

Comment: @Serge ```Grade``` is just an enum that refers to grade level of a student (First, Second, Third, etc).

Comment: @GertArnold Well that's what's sort of puzzling me. I included the whole error message, don't think it really gives much more details

Comment: @amdorsey12 You still didn't answer my question   what public ICollection<CourseGrade> Grades { get; set; } has in common with ReportCard? How are they related? Did you try to remove it?

Comment: It is a one (ReportCard) to many (CourseGrade)

Comment: Sure, but how exactly is it mapped? Which `CourseGrade` field refers to `ReportCard`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a bug in CourseGrade class

```
public ICollection<CourseGrade> Grades { get; set; }
```

you can't use it like this, Since you don't have ReportCardId,  EF core must be added ReportCardId  as a shadow property to CourseGrade. This is what causes the error. You have to remove records with ReportCardId  from CourseGrade at first. Or remove property Grades if you don't need it and make db migration again

Comment: Yes, this was a key part of my problem. It might have actually been the only compilation error causing bug, hard to tell with all the changes I made; I restructured a lot of my classes that I didn't mention here, including taking that property out of CourseGrade. Ended up having to make an ERD so I could see all that was happening at once